# I'm trying to make a grade average system but with while loops, how can I individually get the outputs from the while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, average

This is what I've came up so far:

Is there like a way to individually get the output/answers from the while loop so I can add and divide them? Or is there another way like a for loop to access them? I'm quite new to coding so thanks in advance!

Comment: im not sure I understand -- can you show an example of what you want in code?

Comment: unit = 0

while unit < 8:
    grades = int(input("Enter Grades: "))
    unit += 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to store multiple grades, and perform operations on them, then a list can help. You can define "grades" as a list variable before the while loop. Then after the loop you can use print() function to see what's in the list.

Using a for loop, you can perform operations with each grade in the list. To get the sum of the grades you can define a "sum" variable and add each grade from the for loop.

Based on what you've said, I think this is a good starting point:

EDIT: Changed variable "sum" to "g_sum" because sum is a built-in Python method. Using a variable by the same name could pose a problem if you tried to use this method.

```
unit = 0
grades = [] # this is the list of grades

while unit < 8:
    # append will add each grade to the list
    grades.append(int(input("Enter Grades: ")))
    unit += 1

# printing all values in the list
print(grades)

# we can already get a denominator from the length of the list
denominator = len(grades)

# for loop to get sum of all grades in list
g_sum = 0
for g in grades:
    g_sum += g

# now we can get the average
average = g_sum / denominator

# printing sum and average of grades
print(f"Sum of grades: {g_sum}\nAverage of grades: {average}")
```

Comment: holy crap this is what I have been trying to do! thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Can you add any more detail, or an example of the loop(s) in question? It looks like you meant to after "...came up so far:"?

Okay. I understand a little better. I have to run in a minute, but, I'll try to point you in the right direction...

You will need to use a list to collect your scores. For example, before your while loop:

score_list = []

While......input grade

score_list.append(grade)

After the While loop...

avg_grade = sum(score_list) / len(score_list)

Comment: unit = 0

while unit < 8:
    grades = int(input("Enter Grades: "))
    unit += 1

Answer (score 0):

You may create an empty list before the loop and then append each entered value to it within a loop:

```
unit = 0
grades = []
while unit < 8: 
    grade = int(input("Enter Grades: "))
    grades.append(grade)
    unit += 1
```

Then you will be able to access any value from the list:

```
print(grades[0])
```

Comment: You may then operate with those values any way you need using list index. There's a good suggestion to your further questions about the sum and the average in @xk_winter answer. I would also recommend you to use `numpy` for such operations, it makes them easy and short:
`import numpy as np`  
`np.sum(grades)`  
`np.mean(grades)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_average():
    count = 0
    total = 0
    while count < 3:
        grade = float(input('Enter grade: '))
        count += 1
        total += grade
    average = total / count
    print(average)
```